# How to Edit the unthorize GSP file in grails - beginner

Tags: grails

I get this message when i dont have permission to access a View.

```
Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.
```

I want to customise this add some css and etc to make this pretty. Where can i find the view to edit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

denied page exists in login folder of spring security plugin. If you are using spring security 1.x then it is in you app views/login/denied and if you are using spring security 2.x then it is in spring security plugin then copy that views/login folder in spring security plugin and paste it in your app views page. Then

add this in your `UrlMappings` file

```
"403"(controller: 'error', action: 'denied')
```

and create a controller `ErrorController`

```
class ErrorController {
    def denied() {
        render(view: '/login/denied')
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 was already there. I added 403 error to `UrlMappings.groovy` but it didn't work. I still see the old ugly error message.

Comment: Yes i did. But still i see the previous error message

Answer (score 3):

Declare the 403 page in grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy

```
"403"(view: '/403')
```

Next, create a grails-app/views/403.gsp view that will contain the content of your access denied page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title>Access Denied</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'stylesheet.css')}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time a 403 error is raise users will see the content of 403.gsp
You can do it as follows from a controller:

//Example of throwing a 403 error from within a controller

```
def authenticateUser() {
    if(!username.isValid(session)) {
         return response.sendError(403)                 
        }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Whichever controller you might think can cause an error. For instance, there is an updateWebsite controller which can be accessed only by admins and not by users. So if users try to access it, it should say permission denied. Thus, while authenticating the user credentials, if their role is not admin, you might add this code to tell them that access is denied. This is just an example. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Within a COntroller class i have some methods which i allow users to access and some for Admins to access. And if a user is trying to access such methods i want to show the 403.gsp view

Comment: I sorted it. May i know what is `updateWebsite controller ` and for what i can use it for?

Comment: So there in the controller class, wherever you are determining the user role, if they are users, navigate them to 403

Comment: That was just an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I sorted the question. Thanks again.

Comment: If this solution works for you, please tick my answer to accept it.